# Replicating a linear regression example from Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman

Tags: regression, python

One of the standing examples in the book *The Elements of Statistical Learning* by Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman (hereafter referred to as *HTF*) uses prostate cancer data (available [here](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/datasets/prostate.data) and described [here](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/datasets/prostate.info.txt)) from a study by Stamey et al. (1989).

I'm trying to reproduce the results quoted in the (second edition of) HTF for ordinary linear regression, for which they report the following coefficients (table 3.2, page 50):

```
Intercept:  2.45
lcavol   :  0.72
weight   :  0.29
age      : -0.14
lbph     :  0.21
svi      :  0.31
lip      : -0.29
gleason  : -0.02
egg45    :  0.28
```

However, my own analysis gives woefully different numbers (using `scikit-learn`'s `LinearRegression`, `statsmodels`'s `OLS` and computing the coefficients manually using formula 3.6 in HTF). I get

```
Intercept:  0.429
lcavol   :  0.577
lweight  :  0.614
age      : -0.019
lbph     :  0.145
svi      :  0.737
lcp      : -0.206
gleason  : -0.030
pgg45    :  0.009
```

using the following (Python 3) code:

```
# Import data
# -----------
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('prostate.data', sep='\t', usecols=range(1, 11))

# Extract training set used by HTF
# --------------------------------
train_mask = (df['train'] == 'T')
cols_X = [col for col in df.columns if col not in ['lpsa', 'train']]
cols_y = ['lpsa']

X_train = df.loc[train_mask, cols_X]
y_train = df.loc[train_mask, cols_y]

# Use scikit-learn's LinearRegression
# -----------------------------------
from sklearn import linear_model

ols = linear_model.LinearRegression(normalize=True)
ols.fit(X_train, y_train)

print('Intercept: {:6.3f}'.format(ols.intercept_[0]))
for i, col in enumerate(X_train.columns):
    print('{:9s}: {:6.3f}'.format(col, ols.coef_[0, i]))

# Use statsmodels OLS
# -------------------
import statsmodels.api as sm

result = sm.OLS(y_train, sm.add_constant(X_train)).fit()
print(result.summary())

# Use formula 3.6 of HTF
# ----------------------
X_ext = np.hstack([np.ones((X_train.shape[0], 1)), X_train.values])
np.matmul(np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(np.matmul(X_ext.T, X_ext)), X_ext.T), y_train)
```

Am I doing something wrong, or are the numbers reported in the book that are wrong?

EDIT: Redefining

```
X_train = (X_train - X_train.mean(axis=0)) / (X_train.std(axis=0))
```

before any of the fits leads to coefficients that are consistent with those  reported in HTF:

```
Intercept:  2.4523
lcavol:     0.7164
weight:     0.2926
age:       -0.1425
lbph:       0.2120
svi:        0.3096
lip:       -0.2890
gleason:   -0.0209
pgg45:      0.2773
```

The book would probably benefit from making this clearer (I've seen other people confused by this same issue). Thanks to all that responded!

Comment: While I haven't looked at this closely, my first guess would be that the parameterization that R uses in linear regression is different than scikit-learn's regression.  How does scikit-learn handle the parameterization of categorical variables?

Comment: @Analyst1: the two categorical features (`svi` and `gleason`) are reported as integers, and are fed into `scikit-learn` (and `statsmodels`, and the manual computation) as such.

Comment: I'm *guessing* that is the problem.  Take a careful look to see how these are treated in Hastie's book.  I suspect they are treated as factors in R, in which case they would be converted to 0/1 variables with one category set to zero.  This could certainly explain the differences.  I'd review that carefully.

Comment: @Analyst1: I doubt that's the case: the book reports a *single* coefficient for both `svi` and `gleason`. While the first one takes values in the set `{0, 1}`, `gleason` can be any of `{6, 7, 8, 9}`.

Comment: Fair enough.  Like I said, it was just a guess and I didn't have the book in front of me to look carefully.  This is common problem when people try to match examples, so it was my best guess without all the info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As they say in the text:

> We fit a linear model to the log of prostate-specific antigen, lpsa,
>   after first standardizing the predictors to have unit variance. We
>   randomly split the dataset into a training set of size 67 and a test
>   set of size 30. We applied least squares estimation to the training
>   set, producing the estimates, standard errors and Z-scores shown in
>   Table 3.2

You have not standardized the predictors.

Comment: Yes, I have: notice the `normalize=True` in `scikit-learn`'s `LinearRegression`. In any case, setting `normalize=False` gives the same results.

Comment: What EXACTLY does normalize=True do?  I couldn't find any documentation which says (haven't looked at source code).

Comment: @Alberto if your results with `normalize=True` are identical to the ones with `normalize=False`, it suggests that something is wrong. Regression coefficients should clearly be different in these two cases.

Comment: @AlbertoGarcía-Raboso you have to normalize the *predictors* and not the outcome. Don't ask me why. HTF just decided that's the way to do it.

Comment: It seems the book reports the coefficients in terms of the normalized predictors (and unnormalized outcomes), while `scikit-learn` fits the normalized predictors but gives the coefficients in terms of the unnormalized predictors. As I say in the edit to the question: the book may benefit from making this more explicit.

Comment: @Alberto García-Raboso And scikit-learn could benefit from making explicit what Normalize=True does.

Answer (score 6):

When I standardize the predictors (i.e. subtract mean and divide by standard deviation), and then do standard OLS on observations marked as belonging to the training set, I get:

```
   2.464932922123745
   0.679528141237975
   0.263053065732544
  -0.141464833536172
   0.210146557221827
   0.305200597125098
  -0.288492772453546
  -0.021305038802948
   0.266955762119924
```

Which is basically the same as described in the text (minor differences remain but probably nothing important and I shouldn't have spent this much time already!)